# How to join two sql tables when the common column has different names but information is the same in both tables

Tags: sql

Relatively new to SQL querying. I can successfully get results from a simple query that shows a customer number and a total dollars invoiced sorted highest dollar amount to lowest.  I want to also display the customer name.  The customer name, `[Name]`, is in another table along with the customer number but the column name for customer number is different, ie. `Table 1` is `[Bill-to Customer No_]` and `Table 2` is just `[No_]`.  How would I get the information from `Table 2` to display in the same row with the customer number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [Bill-to Customer No_], [Invoice Amount] AS amt, [Name]
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.[Bill-to Customer No_] = t2.[No_]
ORDER BY amt DESC;
```

I haven't grasped your column names yet, but hope you get the idea.

***EDIT** : (as per your new query)*

```
SELECT [Sell-to Customer No_], [Name], SUM([Amount]) as "Total Dollars Spent" 
FROM [Table 1 - LIVE$Sales Invoice Line] a JOIN [Table 2 - LIVE$Customer] b
ON a.[Sell-to Customer No_] = b.[No_]
WHERE [Source Code] = 'RENTAL' and [Sell-to Customer No_] != 'GOLF' 
GROUP BY [Sell-to Customer No_], [Name]
ORDER BY SUM([Amount]) DESC;
```

You need to add `[Name]` to the `GROUP BY` clause as well. Remember you cannot `SELECT` a column that's not a part of `GROUP BY` unless it's being processed by a group function like `[Amount]` is being processed by `SUM()`.

Comment: This is not sensitive information so I'm going to post the actual query I have....

Comment: @CraigZirnheld, I've updated your query. You need to fix your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Ok.   To whom do I send the check?  Still learning and look for all references before I ask someone.  Thanks all, so much.

Comment: I'm getting the following error now.  There is an "Amount" column in both tables but they contain unrelated information. Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'Amount'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Ambiguous column name 'Amount'.

Comment: Please, add the table alias to it like `a.[Amount]` everywhere.

Comment: This query:SELECT [Sell-to Customer No_], [Name], SUM([Amount]) 
FROM [CARDINAL CARRYOR - LIVE$Sales Invoice Line] a JOIN [CARDINAL CARRYOR - LIVE$Customer] b
ON a.[Sell-to Customer No_] = b.[No_]
WHERE [Source Code] = 'RENTAL' and [Sell-to Customer No_] != 'GOLF' 
GROUP BY [Sell-to Customer No_], [Name]
ORDER BY a.SUM([Amount]) DESC;       Returns this:Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Ambiguous column name 'Amount'.
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.SUM", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: Table aliases (`a` or `b`) would go with the column name `[Amount]` not function name `SUM`. So, you need `SUM(a.[Amount])` there.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
       [bill-to Customer No_]
       ,customer_name 
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table2 AS b on a.[bill-to Customer No_]=b.No_
```

Comment: @gh9, this is an invalid edit because the join column now does not match the select clause.

Comment: I think it should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Bill-to, CustomerNo_ ,customer_name 
from Table1 a 
join Table2 b on a.CustomerNo_ = b.No_
```

Comment: SELECT    [Table 1 - LIVE$Sales Invoice Line].[Sell-to Customer No_],[Table 2 - LIVE$Customer].[Name], 
[Table 1 - LIVE$Sales Invoice Line].sum([Amount]) as "Total Dollars Spent"
FROM         [Table 1 - LIVE$Sales Invoice Line] a 
join  [Table 2 - LIVE$Customer] b on a.[Sell-to Customer No_]= b.[No_]
where [Source Code] = 'RENTAL'
and [Sell-to Customer No_] != 'GOLF'
group by [Sell-to Customer No_]

Comment: @CraigZirnheld: That comment is not very clear. What do you mean with that code?

Comment: I meant with the SQL Query I just posted above this is the error I get when I run the query.   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Ambiguous column name 'Amount'.
Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.SUM", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: I figured it out.  I was typing a.sum([Amount]) instead of sum(a.[Amount])